# Current research on Gödel machines

Tags: reference-request, agi, problem-solving, godel-machine

Is there any current research on Gödel machines? It seems that the last article by Jürgen Schmidhuber on this topic was published in 2012: [http://people.idsia.ch/~juergen/goedelmachine.html](http://people.idsia.ch/%7Ejuergen/goedelmachine.html)

Answer (score 1):

This paper [Can Machines Design? An Artificial General Intelligence Approach](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.02091.pdf) (2018, presented at [AGI-18](http://agi-conference.org/2018/) and published in the related proceedings [here](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319976754)), which proposes the **design Gödel machine**, may be useful to you.

After a quick search, I have not found other relevant papers, so I suppose that the research on GMs is currently not very active.